# Can't use if condition using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, page-objects

I've got the following situation:

I want to fill a field which is displayed some times and others don't.
So, to solve this I used a if condition along with page objects.

```
 public static WebElement Field(WebDriver driver) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 9)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
        .xpath("element")));

    return element;
```

The if condition is:

```
if (PageObject.Field(driver).isDisplayed()) {
        PageObject.Field(driver).sendKeys("Lorem Ipsum Dolor");
    }
```

The problem is that if the field is not displayed, the script fails because the element is not found and the if condition is not used. I tried the following and didn't work either:

```
boolean test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).isDisplayed();

    if (test) {
        PageObject.Field(driver).sendKeys("Lorem Ipsum Dolor");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check needs to happen before you get to the `.isDisplayed()` method. The way `WebDriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated())` works, it will return either the element or throw an exception.

I'd suggest something like this in your element find code:

```
public static WebElement Field(WebDriver driver) {

  try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 9)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
    .xpath("element")));

    return element;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
```

Then, in your search code:

```
if (PageObject.Field(driver) != null) {
  // logic for handling the field goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it worked. It takes some time to check the element is not displayed (9 seconds according to my code), but even thought it is a very good solution.

Comment: How are you differentiating the case where it should be displayed but actually not displayed (defect)and vice versa?

Comment: Actually I'm using only to fill some fields if they are displayed or not. To verify the condition you said "not displayed = defect" I just use the **PageObject.Field(driver).isDisplayed();** and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for presence of element. Use Java's equivalent of Python's `are_present()`. It will return list of matching elements, empty is none are present.

Comment: I tried with: 

elementToBeClickable(locator)
visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator)
presenceOfElementLocated(locator)

and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to this one

package com.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.Assert;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class IfExampleSelenium
{

@Testpublic void testPageTitle()

{

System.out.println("Launching Firefox browser..");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");

String expPageTitle = "Google";

boolean flag = false;

if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(expPageTitle))

{

flag = true;

System.out.println("Yeah... Page title matched");

}

Assert.assertTrue(flag, "Page title is not matching with expected");

}

}